# Strange behaviour with iOS UIImageView and App going into background

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a method, and in this method, there is this conditional:

```
if (self.sleepingCharacter.objectSprite.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"sleepingRight.png"])
{....
```

This normally works fine.  But I've noticed, in the iOS simulator, that when I put my App in the background by pressing command-H, and then i bring my app back, this conditional no longer works.   Do you know why this would happen?

I tested to see if the code would work if I wrote this:

```
if (self.sleepingCharacter.objectSprite.image)
{....
```

And it did work, which means that there is still an image there.  Now I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `==` operator to compare the two images. This will only be true of the two images are actually the same hunk of memory (the same pointer).

The `UIImage imageNamed:` method caches images. So in theory if you call it again and again for the same image name, you will keep getting the same pointer and your code appears to work.

But the image cache can get purged at times due to memory usage. Once the image gets purged, the next call to `imageNamed:` will return a new image pointer and your check will fail.

You need a better way to see if the two images are the same. One solution is to convert both images to `NSData` objects using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` then compare the two `NSData` objects using the `isEqual:` method.

Comment: @faunta As a bit of an optimization, I would keep the current check. If that fails, then perform the additional check I outlined. I suggest this because most times your current check will work and my suggestion is much less efficient.